# Rails doesn't load assets properly in production environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5, yarnpkg

I'm trying to deploy my application to a Digital Ocean Docker droplet.

In development environment, all styles load correctly, but when i upload to production not. See the screen below

[image]

I'm using:

- Rails 5.2
- Yarn
- Docker
- Docker Compose

I'm forgetting something?

Command that i already runned on prodution:

```
docker-compose run app bundle exec rails secret

docker-compose run app bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

docker-compose run app bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate db:seed RAILS_ENV=production

docker-compose run app yarn install RAILS_ENV=production

docker-compose run app yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of these `docker-compose run` commands work in a new container. This will not work.

There are several ways to solve this, one of them is to compile your assets and do all preparations in a docker entrypoint.